# Matplotlib 1.5 usage of axes.prop_cycle

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

`axes.color_cycle` is deprecated in Matplotlib 1.5. However its usage was quite straightforward: we could easily grab a specific color by:

```
plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'][color_number]
```

`axes.prop_cycle` does not support this syntax:

```
ValueError: Can only use slices with Cycler.__getitem__
```

And cycler doc is not very detailed http://matplotlib.org/cycler/

So I don't know how I can get a specific color from prop_cycle. Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

To get the value you want:

```
list(mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])[1]['color'])
```

There is an open [PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/cycler/pull/26) to add a `by_key` method to `Cycler` objects so this will eventually be

```
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'][1]
```

There are also some discussions about mapping the color `'c1'` to the first color in the `prop_cycle`, but that has not been implemented yet.

I am the main author of the cycler docs, what additional detail would you want to see there?

Comment: list(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])[1]['color'] works fine! Thanks

Regarding the docs, it explains well how to create a cycler but it wasn't very explicit about the way of using existing cycler, such as axes.prop_cycle.

Answer (score 2):

```
colors = [color['color'] for color in list(mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])]
colors[1]
```

is a way to restore the old use. First line returns a 2-D array of colors.