# Hand-pick a color from the Axes' current color cycler

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to manually select a color from the pallette that belongs to the style I am using. I would have expected a `get_prop_cycle` method to exist (because `set_prop_cycle` also exists), but that doesn't seem to be the case. What is the proper way to hand-pick a color from the current color cycler?

(I'm using matplotlib v1.5.3)

Comment: I think this already has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37038283/4124317)

Comment: Indeed, problem solved. Thanks!